# Docker build times long with npm global install angular-cli

Tags: node.js, docker, angular-cli, alpine-linux

I have encountered a very strange scenario and was wondering if anyone was able to shed some light on the situation. In short, `docker build` with `npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16` along with the rest of application steps takes forever to build. `docker build` with that alone in it's own image, then `docker build` the rest of the app `FROM` that first image, together or individually they do not take that long. When I say long, I mean like 2 hours. The individuals take around 5 to 7 min to build.

So before I lay down all the code, a few notes. I have tried this on OS X 10.10.5, OS X 10.11.X, OS X 10.12.X, Arch Linux 4.5.1-1-ARCH, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (in a vagrant box, and in AWS), as well as some friends have helped me with this on their machines. All same results. I am running Docker 1.12.1. and I'm building `FROM alpine:3.4`. The version of `node` is `v6.2.0` and `npm` 3.8.9 (from the alpine packages). I have also tried this with a image that I built nodejs v5.11.1 and npm 3 from source.

```
FROM alpine:3.4
MAINTAINER First Lastname <user@example.com>

ARG ENV

#Set environment vars
ENV HOME=/home \
    APP_DIR=/root/app \
    DIST_DIR=/var/www \
    ENV=${ENV} \
    AWS_REGION=us-east-1 \
    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

#Install runtime packages
RUN apk --no-cache add \
          ca-certificates \
          nodejs \
          nginx

#Install build time packages
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        --virtual build-dependencies \
          busybox \
          build-base \
          bzip2 \
          git \
          python-dev \
          libffi-dev

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
COPY . ${APP_DIR}

#Bug https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9863
RUN cd $(npm root -g)/npm && \
    npm install fs-extra && \
    sed -i -e s/graceful-fs/fs-extra/ -e s/fs\.rename/fs.move/ ./lib/utils/rename.js && \
    rm -fr ${APP_DIR}/node_modules

#install node packages
RUN npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16 && \
    npm install -g typescript@2.0.3 && \
    npm install && npm install -g --save process-nextick-args && npm cache clean | tee /tmp/npm-install.log

#build project
RUN ng build  --environment=${ENV}
RUN mv dist ${DIST_DIR}

#clean up
RUN rm -fr ${APP_DIR}
RUN apk del build-dependencies

#nginx config
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ && \
    chmod -R 755 /etc/nginx/sites-*
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
COPY ./nginx/account-curation.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/account-curation.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

#app port
EXPOSE 80 81

#start nginx
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx" ]
```

And package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular2-material/button": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/card": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/core": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/grid-list": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/icon": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/input": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/input": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/list": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/tabs": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "angular2-modal": "2.0.0-beta.13",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "jstree": "3.3.1",
    "localStorage": "1.0.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.32",
    "@types/jstree": "^3.3.32",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

I'm pointing this out because it already has all the packages I'm trying to install globally (same version) but when this installs it's much quicker. So this takes around 2 hours to build. Insane right? So after fooling with this for days I can't figure out why. I decided in light of time I'd build a base image with the global installs in there, then build the project image `FROM` that one. That way the CI build job would not take hours on every push to this repositories branch. But when I did this, it magically got faster. Around 7min for the base image, and 5 for the app image. It looked something like this.

Base Image:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
MAINTAINER First Lastname <user@example.com>

#Set environment vars
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

#Install runtime packages
RUN apk --no-cache add \
          ca-certificates \
          nodejs

#Install build time packages
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        --virtual build-dependencies \
          busybox \
          build-base \
          bzip2 \
          git \
          python-dev \
          libffi-dev

#Bug https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9863
RUN cd $(npm root -g)/npm && \
    npm install fs-extra && \
    sed -i -e s/graceful-fs/fs-extra/ -e s/fs\.rename/fs.move/ ./lib/utils/rename.js

#install node packages
RUN npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16 && \
    npm install -g typescript@2.0.3 && \
    npm install -g --save process-nextick-args && npm cache clean | tee /tmp/npm-global-install.log

RUN apk del build-dependencies

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/ash" ]
```

Application Image

```
FROM company/application_base:latest
MAINTAINER First Lastname <user@example.com>

ARG ENV

#Set environment vars
ENV APP_DIR=/root/app \
    DIST_DIR=/var/www \
    ENV=${ENV} \
    AWS_REGION=us-east-1 \
    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

#Install runtime packages
RUN apk --no-cache add \
          ca-certificates \
          nginx

#Install build time packages
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        --virtual build-dependencies \
          busybox \
          build-base \
          bzip2 \
          git \
          python-dev \
          libffi-dev

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
COPY . ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

#install node packages
RUN npm install && npm cache clean | tee /tmp/npm-install.log

#build project
RUN ng build && mv dist ${DIST_DIR}

#clean up
RUN rm -fr ${APP_DIR} && apk del build-dependencies

#nginx config
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ && \
    chmod -R 755 /etc/nginx/sites-* && \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
COPY ./nginx/account-curation.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/account-curation.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

#app port
EXPOSE 80 81

#start nginx
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx" ]
```

I do not know `nodejs` that well so something I tried to avoid installing `angular-cli` twice, was `npm install` the one from the `package.json` then `mv` it from the `/path/to/app/node_modules/.bin/ng` to the `/usr/bin` also just adding the `/path/to/app/node_modules/.bin` to my path, both resulted in a `ng not found`.

Not sure it's related but I will call it anyone, I keep getting this annoying npm gyp permissions issue only for globally installed packages. `gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the dev dir` They where just warnings but I thought I would google it and see what it was about. Just to rule out possibilities I tried suggested approaches to fix that from posts like https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions
and 
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/454
Nothing I could find worked.

Something else I tried is messing with the amount of ram and cpu's that docker can utilize. such as `docker build --build-arg ENV=dev --cpuset-cpus "0-5" --no-cache -t company/app_name:0.1.0 .`.

I really do not want to maintain two `Dockerfile`'s, especially when I feel like there is something really dumb I am missing. Because I know they work much better when apart. What in the heck could cause this to increase the build time by so much when it's all together.

Answer (score 1):

The "all" image build takes a long time due to issues with `execSync` and `node-zopfli` building their native modules very slowly. Both are optional dependencies so the install survives them not working but they take a looooong time to fail.

The divided image build makes both those two packages fail to build quickly. I'm really not sure how that's happened though as there appear to be a number of changes that can cause them to fail to build quickly.

#### execAsync

The execSync module shouldn't even exist anymore, it's for node 0.10. 
If I remove the `npm` bug fix from the `Dockerfile`, the execAsync build fails immediately rather than taking a long time to fail.

#### node-zopfli

To remove the permission issues use `npm install --unsafe-perm` to allow the build to run as the `root` user in the container.

#### devDependencies

Use either the `devDependencies` or the global installs for your `ng` build, not both. An `npm install --production` will remove the `devDependencies` from the app install which means `angular-cli` is not duplicated any more. If you need more of the devDependencies to complete the app build then you might want to go the other way, and not do the global installs but rely just on the devDepenencies (`./node_modules/.bin/ng`)

#### Other Notes

Use `FROM mhart/alpine-node:6` to get a recent version of node/npm and don't install `nodejs` via `apk`.

Set the `ARG ENV` and `ENV ENV` as late as possible (i.e. just before the `ng` command that uses it) so that an environment change doesn't trigger a complete rebuild of the image.

There is no image size to gain (or lose really) when running clean up steps in a later `Dockerfile` command like `RUN apk del build-dependencies`. The files are already committed to a previous image layer by this time.

When doing repeated docker image builds, use something like [verdacio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio)/[npm-register](https://github.com/dickeyxxx/npm-register) for npm and/or [apt-cacher-ng](http://apt-cacher-ng) for generic os packages. They will remove most of the network overhead for repeated docker builds.

#### Dockerfile

So you end up with something like this:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6.7
MAINTAINER First Lastname <user@example.com>

# Set environment vars
ENV HOME=/root \
    APP_DIR=/root/app \
    DIST_DIR=/var/www \
    AWS_REGION=us-east-1 \
    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

# Install packages
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        --virtual build-dependencies \
        ca-certificates \
        nginx \
        build-base \
        bzip2 \
        git \
        python-dev \
        libffi-dev

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
COPY . ${APP_DIR}

# Install node packages
RUN set -uex ;\
    npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16 typescript@2.0.3 process-nextick-args ;\
    npm install --production --unsafe-perm ;\
    npm cache clean

ARG ENV
ENV ENV=${ENV}

# Build project
RUN set -uex ;\
    ng build  --environment=${ENV} ;\
    mv dist ${DIST_DIR} ;\
    rm -fr ${APP_DIR}

# nginx config
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN set -uex ;\
    mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ ;\
    chmod -R 755 /etc/nginx/sites-* ;\
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log ;\
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
COPY ./nginx/account-curation.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/account-curation.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

# App port
EXPOSE 80 81

# Start nginx
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx" ]
```

There's no problem with having two Dockerfiles either. As each should do their own thing and not duplicate the others actions. You normally only *need* to do this when you have multiple images to build from the one base image though.

Answer (score 0):

Worth pointing out that *may* be related is to add this as well before the npm install steps:

```
RUN npm config set maxsockets 10
```

On older versions of npm it is infinity, on newer ones it is 50.
I got a huge speed boost when setting it explicitly to 10 myself (vaguely remember someone who said 25 was good for him).